# How to programmatically install nvm and install / use npm?

Tags: bash, shell, npm, zsh, nvm

SO...

I have created some scripts to help configure my shell, but I am having an issue with nvm. My script looks like...

```
#!/bin/zsh
set -Eeuo pipefail

echo 'Installing nvm'
touch $HOME/.zshrc
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | zsh

echo 'Setting default'
echo 'stable' >  $HOME/.nvmrc

echo 'Installing default'
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

nvm install
nvm use
```

...but I am getting...

```
N/A: version "stable -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install stable" to install it before using it.
```

...but when I run `nvm install` on my terminal, it works as expected. I tried wrapping `nvm install` with eval(), $(), but nothing seems to work, what am I missing? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try `command -v nvm` in the script to make sure it is considered to exist and is accessible. You probably need to run the code NVM says to run after installing, to enable it in the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @l3l_aze! `command -v nvm` in my script does return successfully, so that's good. Running the code NVM says to in my terminal works, but the whole point is to avoid having to run commands manually.

Comment: Yes, that was just to confirm nvm is working. Have you tried without the `set -Eeuo pipefail` statement? How about quoting the variables? How about skipping trying to set the default before installing something? I've automated nvm setup and having it install npm + node similarly in Bash and it works fine. Did not set a default like this though, just running `nvm install lts/*`

Comment: Ah, thanks @l3l_aze! It was `set -E` that was causing the problem. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer provided by @l3l_aze!

`set -E` at the top of the shell script was the culprit, so I changed my script to be...

```
#!/bin/zsh
set -euxo pipefail
```

...and it works!

Comment: While it's good to have an answer we only know what was causing the problem, not why it was behaving that way. I'm no expert, but I think it was the combination of `-e` and `-E`: the `-e/-o errexit` tells the script to exit on first error, and `-E/-o errtrace` causes some extra error handling that doesn't normally exist otherwise. Glad it's working though :) Cheers.

Comment: I have since abandoned trying to do this myself and have instead opted for [zsh-nvm](https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm)